# disk become empty after delete a large file

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, disk-space, disk-format

I have a 2T mobile disk with the format of NTFS. I store 1T files on it, including a large file with the size of 260G.

After I delete the large file, all the file was gone. I remount the disk again and again , it remains the same. I am using os x lion.

Here is the result of `df -h`

```
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity   iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2   931Gi  486Gi  445Gi    53% 127448441  116532301   52%   /
devfs          332Ki  332Ki    0Bi   100%      1149          0  100%   /dev
map -hosts       0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%         0          0  100%   /net
map auto_home    0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%         0          0  100%   /home
/dev/disk1s1   1.8Ti  874Gi  989Gi    47%     57185 1036883723    0%   /Volumes/Seagate Backup Plus Drive
```

Notice the last line, **874Gi Used** but **0% iused**. What I can concluded is the files are still on the disk but I can't see them. Maybe some inode is broken.

So how can I save my file on the disk. Any method to copy the file to another disk or repair the mobile disk?

Comment: There are 57185 inodes used, so the file is still somewhere. How did you delete the file? Did you empty the trash afterwards (before ejecting the drive)? 57185/1036883723 gives such a small number that the 0% is just a rounding issue.

Comment: @patrix I delete the file with right click and choose remove. `ls -al` on the disk  gives nothing. I have tried some recover  software. They showed there are some file in the disk but a lot of them are broken.

Comment: After deleting in Finder you **must** empty the Trash to physically remove the file. To check that it is there just open the trashcan while the disk is mounted.

Comment: @patrix. No there aren't files in the trashcan after mount the disk.  The problem is I want to recover the file I store in the disk.  I didn't delete them. They just disappear after I delete a large file.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't get that part. OS X doesn't support writing on NTFS drives by default, which NTFS driver are you using?

Comment: @patrix `cd /sbin; mv mount_ntfs mount_ntfs_orig; vim mount_ntfs` and mount_ntfs contains `/sbin/mount_ntfs_orig -o rw,nobrowse "$@"`

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I try is testdisk. Choose the advanced mode, I find my files all are there. Cheers!

I copy them all out. Then I try further to get the disk repaired so that it show all files.  But further try on testdisk results nothing.

Then I google a little more. And find ntfs is more compatible in windows. So I mount the disk on windows and use chkdsk. 10 min later, all things become right!